# My image doesn't show until after my slideshow then when slideshow starts again, it disappears

Tags: javascript, html, css

My image doesn't show until after my slideshow is done and it disappears immediately it starts again, I personally think it is the JavaScript that has the problem code below.

(HTML)

```
<h1 style="font-family: cursive; color: blue;">Jay<i style="color: pink;" class="fa fa-heart"></i>CeeZ</h1>

<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i> News</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> About</a>
  <a href="#" style="float: right; size: 25px; color:#ffffff;"><i onclick="myFunction()" class="fas fa-toggle-off"></i></a>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="girl.jfif" style="width: 100%; height: 450px; ">
  <div  class="text-block">Up to 25% discount off women jacket <a href="women.html" style="text-decoration: none; background-color: red; width: 203;" >Shop Now!</a> </div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="boy.jfif" style="width: 100%;  height: 450px;">
  <div  class="text-block">New Shirt Collection for Men <a href="men.html" style="text-decoration: none; background-color: red; width: 203;" >Shop Now!</a>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">

  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="girl2.jfif" style="width: 100%;color: black; height: 450px; ">
  <div  class="text-block">Up to 15% discount for every first timer <a href="#collection" style="text-decoration: none; background-color: red; width: 203;" >Shop Now!</a></div>
  <div>
  </div>

<br>


<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span>

</div>
<br>
<h1>Women Rocks</h1>
<img src="girl.jfif" alt="first dress" width="203">
```

Could it be the HTML because I don't understand? So this is the CSS code below.

(CSS)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; overflow: scroll;}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
  .text-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  word-break: keep-all;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}
div.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.mySlides{
  width: 100;
  height: 50;
  }

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.active {
  background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: flexbox;

  }
}
.dark-mode {
  background-color: #000900;
  color:red;

}
</style>
```

The JS is very long though, I reviewed it but it doesn't seem like it has problem, even CSS looks okay, the html is just perfect.

(JS)

```
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

Comment: If the code editor tells you that you need to add more material, _please_ do not add rubbish to get around it. That is an abuse of the system, and makes work for other people. The purpose of the restriction is that we want to keep (good) questions forever here, and we want them to be readable and understandable. Our experience is that a lot of code with minimal explanation may not be understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third slide div (with class mySlides) have not close tag (`</div>`), so the elements below it will be treat as content of this last slide, that's why they will show and disappear with it. I think the `<div>` after the text-block and before `</div>` in the third mySlides may be redundant, you can get rid of it and try again.